# Intel Z3735F 1.3 GHz 4-core VS. 1.8 GHz 2-core

Tags: cpu, performance, tablet, cpu-cores

So I have these two Insignia tablets that seem to have absolutely identical hardware except for different processor speeds and cores.

1 - http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/insignia-insignia-8-32gb-window-8-tablet-with-intel-z3735f-quad-core-processor-black-only-at-best-buy-ns-15ms0832b-c/10369413.aspx?path=d50b29a302e156ab267567894a4dfcf3en02

2 - http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-ca/product/insignia-insignia-8-32gb-window-10-tablet-with-intel-z3735f-dual-core-processor-black-ns-15ms0832b-10-c/10386069.aspx?path=71fd7763b35a370e654971536a184753en02

The first one has Intel Z3735F **Quad-Core** at **1.3 GHz**, while the other one also has Intel Z3735F but **Dual-Code** at **1.8 GHz**.

So my question is here: which is better performance-wise? Is there any idea on that matter? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure there is a typo there.. there is no Dual Core Z3735F processor. The Z3735F processor is a quad-core 1.33Ghz processor with bursting speed up to 1.83Ghz. Either the specs are incorrect, or the processor models are not the same.

http://ark.intel.com/products/80274/Intel-Atom-Processor-Z3735F-2M-Cache-up-to-1_83-GHz

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @fixer1234 Not to argue, but my answer addresses the OP's question directly... It was "which is better performance-wise? Is there any idea on that matter?" the processors are the same or the given information is wrong